# Linux returns "select: Bad file descriptor" error after using "cat"

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I am running a Perl script to read from multiple files on a remote machine. My code looks something like this:

```
open HANDLE, "/usr/bin/ssh $host cat /home/log_1.log /home/log_2.log 2>>./errorLog.log |"
```

Basically I am storing the file contents into HANDLE and all errors go into the errorLog.log file. But in my errorLog.log file I keep seeing "select: Bad file descriptor". I am not sure what's causing this and Google searching did not help very much. So my questions are: what does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

EDIT: In the above command, log_2.log may not exist in the remote machine. In that case, I wanted to output the error message into errorLog.log. So when my script finds that the log_2.log file does not exist in the machine, it should log "cat: /home/log_2.log: No such file or directory" but sometimes I see "cat: /home/log_2.log: No such file or directoryselect: Bad file descriptor" (two error messages without a newline).

Comment: Try once `open HANDLE, "/usr/bin/ssh $host cat /home/log_1.log /home/log_2.log 2>>errorLog.log |"`

Comment: You could try using `strace` to find which file descriptor results in the error. Did you perhaps close fd 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: What exactly is this fd you are speaking of?

Answer (score 1):

I see three things wrong with your code:

1. you aren't checking the return value of `open`
2. you are using the two argument version of `open`
3. and you are using a bareword filehandle

The first will probably tell you what is going wrong, the other two are not wrong per se, but are not Modern Perl.  I would write the code like this

```
open my $fh, "-|", "/usr/bin/ssh $host cat /home/log_[12].log 2>>./errorLog.log"
    or die "could not run remote command: $!";
```

Or better yet

```
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';

my $err = gensym; #deal with stupidity in the IPC::Open3 interface
my $pid = open3 my $in, my $out, $err,
    "/usr/bin/ssh", $host, "cat", "/home/log_[12].log";

while (<$out>) {
    #do stuff with the stdout of ssh
}

While (<$err>) {
    #do stuff with the stderr of ssh
}
```

Comment: Hi Chas, doesn't the `open` function return a PID? If I recall correctly, I don't think I can strace by PID unless if you had another method in mind or unless if I got something wrong?

Comment: `open` does return a pid iff the open involves a pipe (as this case does).